# Adverb of Literature

Tags: word-usage

I would like to know the adverb, **if any**, to the word "Literature ". 
Can we say "Literaturly"? Is this the correct adverb to be used in the following example:

```
Literaturly, the following cases were reported: ...
```

Comment: I agree with @probablyme's answer, but my question is, exactly what are you trying to say?  What do you *mean* when you say "literarily" (or whatever other word you choose)?  "In a literary way, the following cases were reported"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the adverb you are looking for is

> [literarily](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/literary)

But I don't think I have ever really seen this word used before.

To me

> Literaturly/literarily , the following cases were reported: ...

sounds strange. I would simply say

> In literature, the following cases were reported:...

Maybe even

1. Regarding literature
2. With respect to literature
3. Concerning literature

Answer (score 0):

There is no adverb in English which will modify the verb in the way you want. If by "literature" you mean a body of specialized writing, such as "scientific literature," your phrase could properly be written as: "The following cases were reported in literature in the subject:" or just "The following cases were reported in the literature:"